# UITableView.visibleCells not capturing all visible cells

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to animate a table view cells on the initial load. The animation works fine for all the cells, except for the last one at the bottom of the table which refuses to animate.

This is because the `UITableView.visibleCells` does not return this cell at the end. (it returns cells 0-12, the last cell is at index 13 and is clearly visible)

Here is the code. Is there anything I can do to ensure all the cells get animated?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()

    let cells = tableView.visibleCells
    let tableHeight: CGFloat = clubsTable.bounds.size.height

    for i in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = i as UITableViewCell
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, tableHeight)
    }


    var index = 0

    for a in cells {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = a as UITableViewCell

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, delay: 0.05 * Double(index), usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
            }, completion: { (complete) in

        })

        index += 1
    }
}
```

Comment: not an answer but I need to know to answer, try to add the height of the table by +30points, does it consider them 13 and animate it?

Comment: yes adding 30 to the table height makes it animate correctly

Comment: that is because the height of your table is less than the height of 13 cells. Thus it animates 12 cells. What you can do is to make the tableHeight bigger in 30px, and after the animation is done, change the height back to normal.

Comment: Much appreciated, and glad it worked out! I posted my answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because the height of your table is less than the height of 13 cells. Thus it animates 12 cells. What you can do is to make the table height bigger in 30px (or any px until it contains 13 cells), and after the animation is done, change the height of the tableView back to normal.

Comment: It's so dumb that we have to do this. Partially visible is still visible. Come on Apple..

Answer (score 0):

after you call `let cells = tableView.visibleCells` can't you just do something like

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: cells.count, inSection: 0)
cells.append(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
```

Going off memory on those function signatures but you get the point.

Comment: returns a nil when I do a `cellForRowAtIndexPath`